# what does " making something hard on somebody" mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

what does " making something hard on somebody" mean? for example when my friend says to me " don't make it hard on yourself", what does it mean? is it slang? if slang, is it American or British?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like he's saying "Don't complicate things." or "Don't make your life difficult." In that case the only usage is "to make it hard on oneself", and is not a multi-word verb in the form "to make sth hard on sb". It's idiomatic.

Comment: I disagree about "*the only usage is 'to make it hard on oneself'*".  I can make something hard on/for someone else.  https://books.google.com/books?id=0nNILMPc5KUC&pg=PA153&dq=%22you+make+it+hard+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIh5DpkofLAhVO4mMKHXeqCFUQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22you%20make%20it%20hard%20on%22&f=false

Comment: @Jim Good quote. I just couldn't find it in any reference.

Comment: @Gandalf see example in my answer. It's pretty common.

Comment: @NVZ except the original was "make", not "be".

Answer (score 1):

### [hard on someone](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hard+on)

> harming someone's feelings; demanding much from someone.
>
> *I wish you wouldn't be so hard on me. So I make mistakes. I never said I was perfect.*